# What's a good LaTeX template for self-publishing a short children's book?

Tags: self-publishing, children, latex

The trick is that the book is in three languages... layout becomes tricky fast. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does three languages mean three columns or what is it you are attempting? Please provide some more details.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is probably more suited to the TeX stack exchange; they've got a similar answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31196/template-for-a-book-for-children), along with some template information. I think you'd be wise to look here before continuing.

The nice thing about LaTeX, however, is that the plain-text nature of it makes it easier to modify existing templates to suit your needs. So, maybe the link I included will point you to something you could use for this. The added benefit here is that you'll get some TeX practice while working on your book.